# Changing Scope of parameter in the simbiology reaction in command line - MATLAB TOOLBOX SIMBIOLOGY

Tags: matlab

I am using Simbiology to construct a model. I am actually reading the model from an SBML file. Here is what I get after I load the model

m1

SimBiology Model - Model1

Model Components:
     Compartments: 1
     Events: 0
     Parameters: 200
     Reactions: 200
     Rules: 0
     Species: 100

However,

m1.Parameters gives

ans =

Empty matrix: 0-by-1

The reason I believe is because all the parameters have "Reaction" Scope. How can I make all of them "Model" Scope by command line?

Also, I was not able to access the parameter (value or scope) through Reaction Object. How do I access Parameter value and Scope (if its is scoped to Reaction)?

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Ayesha

P.S. - I also posted the same enquiry on the Mathworks Newsreader (user forum). Hope someone replies from there or here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pramod also posted an answer on the user forum, but I wanted to copy it here for completeness.

-Arthur

---

The following code illustrates how to change the scope of a parameter from reaction to model.

% Load lotka.
m1 = sbmlimport('lotka')

% There are no Parameters at the model level
m1.Parameters

% Copy the parameters from reactions to the model
for i = 1:numel(m1.Reactions)
    p = m1.Reactions(i).KineticLaw.Parameters;
    copyobj(p,m1)
    delete(p)
end

m1.Parameters

Note that if there is more than one parameter with the same name there will be an error because the model requires unique names for the parameters.

As shown in the above code you can access a reaction scoped parameter by

reaction.KineticLaw.Parameters

Comment: That helps!! Thanks to Arthur (user1368928) and Pramod.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to change the scope of the parameters to Model just to view them - that would change the structure of the model and potentially make it impossible to simulate.

You can view all the parameters in a model using the command

```
sbioselect(m1, 'Type', 'parameter')
```

When a parameter is scoped to a Reaction rather than the model, its parent is the Reaction's KineticLaw, rather than the Reaction itself. So if `r` is your reaction of interest, you can get its parameters with `r.KineticLaw.Parameters`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Sam. That does help, I can atleast access the parameter values now (r.KineticLaw.Parameters). However, I do want to change the scope and now that it won't mess up model. Any ideas how I can do that ?

Comment: If you really need to change the scope of the parameters, you will need to collect them all using `sbioselect` as above, then loop over each of them in a `for` loop. Use `copyobj(p, m1)` to create a new parameter with the same details but with model scope; and then use `delete(p)` to remove the original one.